# WHM: Grant different PHP version for each user

Tags: php, whm

I have a VPS with **WHM** installed. It is running **Centos 6**.

**I want to upgrade only one account's PHP version**. How can I do this?

I'd prefer if I only used the WHM GUI but if I have to mess with config files it's no problem.

**I tried to change the PHP version via the user's .htaccess file, but the browser tried downloading files. I presume I need to install the version I want to use first**

Comment: There's an easy method where you can go to the corresponding domain's `public_html` (or otherwise `www`) directory, edit the `.htaccess` file by adding the required **php** version. Like; `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5 .php4 .php3` . Let me know if it works!

Comment: I tried that but it started downloading files instead of rendering. I'm presuming the version is not installed?

Comment: Yes, indeed. You might want to look into installing and running multiple php versions and managing them. My workaround is what most hosting fellows advise us on. :)

Comment: I didn't spell it out in the question, but this is what I'd like to achieve. Any pointers to where I can start reading how to do this?